# Lotus Notes to SharePoint migration : Best practices

Tags: migration, lotus-notes

We are going to start migrating out 100s of Lotus Notes applications to SharePoint 2010. I know this is not going to be an easy task. I would like get some feedback from people who have already done it. I am more interested in the following.

1. Migration experiences - Good, Bad or Never do it :)
2. Handy Tools
3. Best Practices
4. Lessons learnt
5. Things to keep in mind

Note: Informed MOD to make this CW. Please feel free to close if the Community feels that this question does not have a definite answer.

Comment: I'm happy to leave this open and as community wiki for now, based on [this guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/are-questions-about-best-practices-bad/16601#16601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article has a good overview of the process : http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/developer/a-guide-to-leaving-lotus-notes-and-moving-to-microsoft-sharepoint